# Cannot Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am using innerHTML to add some elements and wrapper on top of it

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    b.innerHTML += "<div class='wrapper'><div class='col-4'>" + arr[i].storeID + "</div>" + 
            "<div class='col-4'>" + arr[i].Bookid + "</div>" + 
           "<div class='col-4'>" + arr[i].StoreName + "</div>" + "</div>"
            var d=document.querySelector('.wrapper')
            d.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                console.log('on click fired')
                /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                inpStr=this.innerHTML
                inp.value = this.innerHTML
                /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                closeAllLists();

            });
}
```

The `innerHTML` is working as expected but when I click the `wrapper` row, I get

> Cannot Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null when using
>   innerHTML

Is this because I am using innerHTML to create an element?

Comment: That sounds pretty strange, are you sure the `.wrapper` element is still in the document? Can you create a [MCVE] that we can debug? Keep in mind that assigning to the `innerHTML` of an element will destroy all listeners on any children of that element

Comment: What is `b` the problem is related to what is b here ??

Comment: If you're relying on ASI and encounter a bug, it may be worth inserting semicolons manually to obviate ASI as a cause...

Comment: `b` is just a DOM element that I made a few lines above the code. 
`b = document.createElement("DIV");`

Comment: If I remove the line where the javascript fails i.e `d.addEventListener` than I can see that the `.wrapper` element is created properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is querySelector only returns the first element with class .wrapper

querySelectorAll() should be used to return an array of .wrappers instead, and iterated through with a for loop to place the event listeners.

Alternatively, you could use a technique known as event delegation and place the event listener on the parent, and use event.target to refer to the child clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am still not sure what is causing the issue. But I changed the code above to something like:

```
$(b).on('click','#wrapper',function(){
    console.log('on click fired')
    /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
    inpStr=this.innerHTML
    inp.value = this.innerHTML
    /*close the list of autocompleted values,
    (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
    closeAllLists();
})
```

and it gives me the right innerhtml. I ust need to figure out how to retrive the just the value from inside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of you have more then one `.wrapper` so you always get only the first created `wrapper` when you execute `var d=document.querySelector('.wrapper')`

You will need th current created wrapper. 
This is what you should do have a look below.

```
var d= document.createElement("div") // Create a new div
b.append(d); // append the new Created div to b
d.className = "wrapper"; 
d.innerHTML =  "<div class='col-4'>" + arr[i].storeID + "</div>" + 
            "<div class='col-4'>" + arr[i].Bookid + "</div>" + 
           "<div class='col-4'>" + arr[i].StoreName + "</div>";
// Add your click operation
d.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                console.log('on click fired')
                /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                inpStr=this.innerHTML
                inp.value = this.innerHTML
                /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                closeAllLists();

            });
```